# Synapse Spark executing SQL (via JDBC driver) funkiness - can't update newly created column, error is "Invalid column name"

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, azure-synapse, jdbc-odbc

If I run this SQL via SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) there is no issue.

```
IF NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE  object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[MyTableName]') AND name = 'Created'
)
  BEGIN
      ALTER TABLE MyTableName ADD Created DATETIME CONSTRAINT DF_MyTableName_Created  DEFAULT(GETDATE())

      UPDATE MyTableName SET Created = '1/1/1900' WHERE Created IS NULL
  END
```

If I try to execute that SQL against a SQL Server instance in a Synapse Notebook, I get the error:

*Exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid column name 'Created'*

It's like the check on the legitimacy of the SQL runs prior to execution when running it from a Spark notebook.

I'd prefer not to run the "UPDATE ... WHERE Created IS NULL" everytime I run the notebook bc it's only going to happen at most one time.

Is there a clever way to get around this error?

Comment: This isn't a JDBC problem, it's how T-SQL works: the `Created` column doesn't exist when the batch is compiled. Have you tried wrapping your update statement in a call to `sp_executesql`? Due to the default constraint, though, the values in the new column should already have the current time so the update statement won't do anything.

Comment: I could try sp_executesql for the update bit and I bet that would work, thanks. I still don't understand why compilation would be different in SSMS vs using the JDBC driver SSMS - no problem. JDBC driver - error. If you add a column with a default to a table, existing records will have a NULL value for the new column, they don't get the default. New records get the default value. I was hoping to make the column non-nullable after the update.

Comment: Maybe because you didn't execute the whole batch in SSMS? If you did you should have seen something similar to: `Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11 Invalid column name 'Created'.` SSMS also has some crazy schema caching, so it might only throw that error in a fresh query tab.

Comment: That's a good thought but I'm sure the entire statement executed bc the column was added and the column values updated